# How to make second adjacent div have auto width that fills the parent container

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="parent clearfix" style="width:100%; height: 100px">

<div style="float: left; width:150px; height: 50%">
</div>

<div style="float: left;" class="target">
</div>

</div>
```

I would like to make class 'target' div be such that it's width is 150px less than the width of the div with class 'parent clearfix'

How do I accomplish this? In the above example the parent div is the child of another div which has a specified width (bit this specified width can change).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `display: table` for the parent and `display: table-cell` for the children ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X9Qsy/)).

```
<div style="width:100%; height: 100px; display: table">
    <div style="display: table-cell; width:150px; height: 50%">
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;">
    </div>
</div>
```

But it will not work in older browsers.

### Update

Another way is to give a `margin-left: 150px` to the second column and a `position: absolute` to the first. This will work in most browsers, but of course it's not a clean version and you'll come in trouble if the first columns content is longer than the second ones. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZJe2j/1/).

Answer (score 1):

It should be just
`width: calc(100%-150px)`
Supported in only CSS3 supporting browsers

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://alistapart.com/article/holygrail for a semi-fluid layout. I think this is exactly what you are looking for.